# sql order by and limit by another value

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have 2 tables, release and release_favourites.

release structure:

```
  id    date (timestamp)    other data
  1     1486901083          ...
  2     1486909903          ...
  ....
```

release_favourites structure:

```
  id    releaseId    userId
  1     2            5
  2     2            10
  ....
```

I want to order records by date (not problem as you can see in SQL), but I want only 10 records with most favourites, is that possible?

(SQL below works, but only for ordering by date)

```
SELECT [some rows]
FROM release AS a, release_favourites AS b
WHERE a.id = b.releaseId
ORDER BY a.date
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  (3) Edit your question and show desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why not use `[table] AS a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [some rows]
FROM release 
WHERE id IN (
       SELECT releaseId 
       FROM (
              SELECT releaseId
              FROM release_favourite
              GROUP BY releaseId
              ORDER BY count(*) 
              DESC LIMIT 10
       )
       AS tmp
)
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select      *

from        release

where       id in
            (
                select      releaseid
                from        release_favourites
                group by    releaseid
                order by    count(*) desc
                limit       10
            )

order by    date
```

Comment: this works, but i cannot use limit in subquery: `This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - non taken, same thoughts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was correct, I only have to add one more subquery

Comment: @nacelnikpohodar - Hi, can you please share your final syntax?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz posted

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want `GROUP BY`.  You only show one table (although your query has two).  This is a (reasonable) guess on what you want:

```
select rf.release_id
from release_favourites rf
group by rf.release_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

You can join in whatever fields you actually want from another table (or use `in` or `exists`).  Not all databases support the ANSI standard `fetch first 10 rows only` syntax.  But all have some way of limiting the result set to a given number of rows.